# Tail server logs into XMPP?

Tags: logging, xmpp, tail

So I have two files, and if a new line appears on either of these files, I'd like to receive an IM (preferably jabber or gTalk) containing the contents of that line. Do you guys have any suggestions for a Linux daemon or something that could do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are logging trough syslog, [Metalog](http://metalog.sourceforge.net/) has support to execute a command whenever a message matching some criterion gets logged. Otherwise, you can use `tailf` to watch for new lines in a log file.

[sendxmpp](http://sendxmpp.platon.sk/) is a small perl script to send XMPP messages (possibly already available as a package for your favorite distribution)

You could stitch those two together with a shell script without too much difficulty. For the metalog case, create a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $* |sendxmpp your-xmpp-id@gmail.com
```

And add `command = /path/to/script.sh` to the relevant section of metalog.conf

For the tailf case, you could try something like this, run in a persistent way:

```
tailf /var/log/file-to-watch.log |(while true; do read M; echo $M | sendxmpp recipient@gmail.com; done)
```

sendxmpp needs a valid XMPP account, see the man page for how to configure the account to be used.

(from my experience, XMPP-delivered error messages tend to become quite annoying if they're too frequent...)

Comment: Hilarious. I just found sendxmpp and set something like this up. Hadn't heard of tailf though, thanks.

Comment: Side note:  In case of problems, check the buffering behavior of your pipe!  (If you're `grep`ing, you probably have to add `--line-buffered` to the incantation for messages to show up.)  I just spent a good hour trying to find out why messages appeared haphazardly or not at all.

Answer (score 2):

I made that little python script. You can use it as a starting point

```
import xmpp, os, time

login     = 'Your.Login' # @gmail.com
pwd       = 'YourPassword'
recipient = 'YourFriend@gmail.com'
logfile   = "/home/myself/test.log"

def sendmsg(text):
  global login, pwd, recipient
  cnx = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
  cnx.connect( server=('talk.google.com',5223) )
  cnx.auth(login,pwd, 'botty')
  cnx.send( xmpp.Message( recipient , text ) )

oldsize = newsize = os.path.getsize(logfile)
while True:
  newsize = os.path.getsize(logfile)
  if newsize != oldsize:
    f = open(logfile)
    f.seek(oldsize, os.SEEK_SET)
    s = f.read()
    if s[-1] == '\n':
      sendmsg(s)
      oldsize = f.tell()
    f.close()
  time.sleep(10)
```

I used information on [that page](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/214.html) for connecting xmpppy to Google Talk.

Comment: Does this require any Python dependancies or is XMPP included with Base?

Comment: You have to install it from http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/